# Plone 4 buildout error

Tags: plone, file-permissions, buildout

Does anyone know how I can fix this error that I get when I do a buildout?

```
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1866, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 625, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1345, in _call
    return f()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.precompiler-0.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/precompiler/__init__.py", line 29, in install
    return self._run()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.precompiler-0.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/precompiler/__init__.py", line 35, in _run
    self._compile_eggs()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.precompiler-0.6-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/precompiler/__init__.py", line 67, in _compile_eggs
    py_compile.compile(fn, None, None, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py", line 123, in compile
    with open(cfile, 'wb') as fc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/products/MyScriptModules/__init__.pyc'
```

Comment: You are not running buildout as a user with write permissions to that directory. Perhaps you originally installed the buildout with `sudo`?

Comment: Thanks, Martjin. I've tried running the buildout as the root user, and also as a non-root sudoer, but neither work. :/

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/products/MyScriptModules/__init__.pyc` or it's parent directory/directories then?

Comment: It looks like there is nothing inside /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/products/ except for README.txt. The folder MyScriptModules doesn't exist.

Comment: And do you have write permission to the `products` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have write permission to that directory.

Comment: Interesting, so for some reason the precompile recipe expects to have to write egg `.pyc` files into that directory but there is no original Python file to count for it. Is this the Plone Universal Installer? If so, I'll leave it to the main maintainer (who also answers SO Plone questions).

Comment: Yes, I used the universal installer (by following this tutorial: http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/production/ubuntu_production.html).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file that causes the problem. which is:

```
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/products/MyScriptModules/__init__.pyc
```

Then re-run buildout as the user that removed the above file.